# () operator overloading c++

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I have some confusion about the calling of the overloaded operator().

There are two functions in class matrix:

```
float operator()(int, int) const; // suppose I call this function rvalue
float& operator()(int, int); // and lvalue
```

now when I call them in main, in this way :

```
Matrix M2(3, 2);
M2(0, 0) = 1; // here lvalue should be called
int c=M2(0,0); // and here rvalue
```

but in both cases it calls lvalue function. why??

if I comment lvalue function and I do

```
int c=M2(0,0); // now it calls rvalue function
```

but in presence of both functions, it calls lvalue function. why?

Hope, my question is clear.

Comment: Im wondering why this is not ambigious

Comment: Your terminology isn't correct - a `const` member function is called for an object which is being accessed through an expression of `const` type. It's nothing to do with lvalues or rvalues.   In your example code none of the expressions are `const`, so that version is not called.

Comment: `M2` is not `const`, so the non-const operator is a better match.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rvalues of class types are not `const` as you might think. The `const` overload will be called on `const` qualified objects, but otherwise the least qualified version is preffered.

What you can do is overload with ref-qualifiers (C++11 only):

```
float operator()(int, int) && const; // called when object is rvalue 
float& operator()(int, int) &;       // called when object is lvalue
```